# Artisan command aborts with no output when reaches model query with "::all()" or "::orderBy()->get()". What is happening?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan

I have to do some changes in a database table with more than 50k rows. The model for the given table is called "Question".
I made an artisan command script that runs through the whole table by using a call getting all rows:

```
$questions = Question::orderBy('id')->get();
```

The script ran great at my local machine, tested it running for 2500 rows and it was flawless so I went to production, but when I'm trying to run it on production, as it reaches the `Question::orderBy('id')` it stops abruptly with no output to CLI console.
I tried changing it to `Question::all()` for getting all rows like `orderBy()->get()` but not ordered, but same outcome, no output and the script stops.

I tried using `dd()` to check what is happening and it stops exactly on the line call for `all()` or `orderBy()`.

I tried debugging with `echo` calls and it is exactly at the line where `all()` or `orderBy()->get()` is called that the command line command stops with no errors showing.

The script is also loaded with `echo` and `print_r` calls to check the progress so there is no way it ran without me knowing.

[image: no output]

The database is correctly configured as the application is running on production with thousand of daily users.

If I try to select a single ID using `find()` and `dd()`, shows that the model is working fine and I can access all values of the given ID row.

[image: if not getting, and only one row it works]

[image: Model works and database is connected]

As you can see see on the images, if the first line is the `orderBy()` call, it stops right at the start with zero errors showing. If I try do to a `find()` with a given ID, it works flawlessly and returns all the rows info so the problem is not the Question model not being called or something like that.

To check if the script would work I even downloaded the dump of the same database on my local MySQL, on a much slower machine than the server running with a Xeon, it was the same amount of rows.

I don't understand what is happening. The connection with the database is working, the same code (the deploy is made using git, so same code), the command is working on my local machine, and also **there is no log output** to `storage/logs/` just like no output to the command line, I have no idea where to begin.

I even tried changing permissions to the artisan command file, but still same output.

By the way, my local machine `.env` is also using "APP_ENV=production" for testing so it is not that.

Any ideas? Am I missing something that I need to do on a production env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is due to the amount of data you're trying to retrieve. It might be causing a 'memory overflow' in the production server. Try chunking the result: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Thank you so much mate, you got me in the right track. The problem was memory but due to the way the infrastructure team configured the PHP for the webserver, I was actually checking the wrong `error_log`.

Using a command to allow more memory for the script to run solved the issue.
`php -d memory_limit=3000M artisan questions:download_questions_imgs`

Comment: @DKage Glad that it helped. But you should still consider using chunks. Because it's the more reliable approach for large datasets.